# PowerShell won't install module

Tags: powershell

I'm really don't know my modules from my manifests when it comes to PowerShell, so hopefully one of you kind folks can get me sorted. I'm trying to install a PowerShell snap-in that comes packaged with a software asset management solution (AdminStudio).

There are no apparent errors, however, I can't invoke commands with the module and the module doesn't populate in a `Get-Module -list`, so I don't believe it installed correctly.

[image]

The documentation describing installation is rather brief, though I don't think anyone's to blame for that. This should be a simple process.

[AdminStudio PowerShell Install Guide](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/adminstudio2015sp1/adminstudio.htm#ashelplibrary/ASplatform_setup.htm#platformapi_4186252975_1064596%3FTocPath%3DAdminStudio%2520Platform%2520API%7C_____2)

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you see when you run `get-pssnapin`?>

Comment: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/5kVceVu.png)

Comment: Ok, that indicates it's not loaded..... run it again with the `-Registered` switch, does it appear then?  If it does, use `add-pssnapin` with the same name found there.

Comment: `get-pssnapin -registered` has no output

Comment: The documentation says `Import-Module -Name [AdminStudioInstallDirectory]\Common\AdminStudio.Platform.PowerShellExtensions.dll`. I don't see that in your screen shot. Do you try it? Generally using modules in PS is a two step process. One is to install them, two is to import them into a PS session.